# Axes inside plot

Tags: oxyplot

How do I change the position of the Axes so that they are inside the plot?

I have this:        [image]

I want this:        [image]

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by using the `AxisTickToLabelDistance` property on your axis definition, like this:

```
plotModel.Axes.Add(new LinearAxis()
{
    Position = AxisPosition.Bottom,
    AxisTickToLabelDistance = -25,
    TickStyle = TickStyle.Crossing,
});
```

Comment: Thanks - just what i was looking for.
PositionAtZeroCrossing also works however for some reason it creates an extra line on the left of the plot.

Comment: For some reason, the lines of the plot go through my axes labels, how do i put axes "On top" ? @Kirenenko

Comment: You can use the property `Layer = AxisLayer.AboveSeries`, but it also will cause the axes being above the series, not just the labels...So its not really a solution I think.